# Java regex for pattern replace - special char and case change to whitespace

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch, regexp-replace

I am trying out Elasticsearch's [pattern char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) for one of our use cases. It uses java regex.

I would like to replace any case change or any special characters with whitespace. There are some good examples in the doc. However, I am looking for one char filter that does the replacement job.

I have been breaking my head in different blogs but no luck :) Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Replace any case change or any special characters with whitespace

Examples:

```
Input: StackOverFlowIsAwesome
Output: Stack Over Flow Is Awesome

Input: stack_over_flow_is_awesome
Output: stack over flow is awesome

Input: stack-over-flow-is-awesome
Output: stack over flow is awesome

Input: stack#over#flow#is#awesome
Output: stack over flow is awesome

..... any special char based inputs

**this one is good, if it is possible**
Input: STACKOverFlowIsAwesome
Output: STACK Over Flow Is Awesome
```

I am using below 2 char filter:

```
          "char_filter": {
            "case_char_filter": {
              "type": "pattern_replace",
              "pattern": "(?<=\\p{Lower})(?=\\p{Upper})",
              "replacement": " "
            },
            "special_char_filter": {
              "type": "pattern_replace",
              "pattern": "[^a-zA-Z0-9]",
              "replacement": " "
            }
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is - are you trying to replace elasticsearch? or replace it's algorithm or just write a java regex?  Or are you struggling with what regex to write to match a specific case? Perhaps post the input and output you are expecting too.

Comment: @MrR thanks for pointing it out. I have added the examples.

Comment: Some of those are fairly straight-forward and general .. i.e. replace a `-` with a space `String.replaceAll("-", " ");`.  What does the first one mean - split on Camel case words?  The last one isn't just a split you want it to make everthing lower case too?

Comment: corrected the last one. 
Not looking for java functions :) Need regex to solve these. As ES would need regex in it's filters.

Comment: Ah I see you want the ES config for doing one of those examples (or all of those examples)?

Comment: all of those in one pattern. I am using 2 patterns for this. Would like to know if one pattern works for this. I have updated the question with the filters I am using

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just setup some char_filters?

The link on the question [PatternReplaceCharFilter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html)  shows an example -

```
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(\\d+)-(?=\\d)",
          "replacement": "$1_"
```

The string format is java source string format (have to double quote `\`).  To replace `_` or `-` or `#` set the regex `"[_-#]+"`, and replacement to `" "`.  gives an example that shows it applies repeatedly.

OR use a [MappingCharFilter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) - although it will convert `stack--overflow` to `stack  overflow` (i.e. same nof spaces as dashes).

The camel case scenario is possibly similar to the example in the documentation -

```
          "pattern": "\b([A-Z])",
          "replacement": " $1"
```

Comment: Look at [java.lang.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for `X|Y  Either X or Y` to merge the two cases.

Comment: I am using the same ES ReplaceCharFilter. `X|Y` is what I needed, working now. 
I am using `(?<=\\p{Lower})(?=\\p{Upper})|[^a-zA-Z0-9]|(?<=\\p{Alpha})(?=\\p{Digit})`. Added for even digits.